# Eclipse 22-09 Java 19 Build Path unspecified error preventing build

Tags: java, eclipse

Trying to build a small java app with jdk17 from an Eclipse 22-09 running on jdk19. App compiles fine from command line with

```
javac src/module-info.java src/xyz/arwhite/pki/*.java --add-exports java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool=pkix --add-exports java.base/sun.security.x509=pkix --add-exports java.base/sun.security.provider=pkix --add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=pkix --add-exports java.base/sun.security.pkcs10=pkix --add-exports java.base/sun.security.pkcs12=pkix --add-exports java.base/sun.security.pkcs=pkix --add-exports jdk.httpserver/com.sun.net.httpserver=pkix -d bin
```

Eclipse however is showing

1. Resource pkix Location Build Path Type Build Path Problem, and a second error
2. Resource pkix Location Unknown Type Java Error.

In Project Settings Build Path there is no error flagged, the correct JDK is associated, the correct additional exports. Nothing to suggest what the problem is that Eclipse has.

Can anyone help with debug settings or some logging or something that will help me figure out what Eclipse doesn't like please?

Editing to add screenshots of the exports etc, really looking to understand though how to trace stuff in Eclipse, there must be some mechanisms for seeing why Eclipse is saying what it's saying.

[image: exports]

module-info.java

```
module pkix {
    requires java.base;
    requires java.net.http;
    requires jdk.httpserver;
}
```

Helpful error messages ...
[image]

Comment: You need to indicate the entire problem descriptions. We can't see what you're seeing based on what you've written. Are all these added exports something you should put into your mudule-info?

Comment: You configured `--add-exports` in _Projects > Properties: Java Build Path_ in the tab _Module Dependencies_, right? Please show your exact project settings and the error message.

Comment: thanks folks, I've added the screenshots, it's no different from with the command line compiler. what I'm really looking for is how to diagnose these types of issues, there's absolutely no meaningful message anywhere, and thinking there has to be some tracing or something.

Comment: In the cropped screenshot, which presumably shows the Problems view, the column _Description_ is not shown (maybe because you made the column too small, scrolled to the right or hide the column via the view menu _Configure Columns..._). Please select both problems, copy them and paste the unmodified text into your question.

Comment: SMH. Thank you very much @howlger, I'd been asking for trace settings or something but the reality is I wasn't actually seeing the error! It hadn't occurred to me, despite using eclipse on and off for > 10 years now, that somehow the view had got corrupt / altered such that it was hiding the actual error message! I'm so used to clicking on the error, it taking me to the code and that's where whatever the flaw is becomes clear. The issue btw was actually an incompatibility between the additional exports from java.base in the build path, and a setting over in the compiler options panel.